# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and frameworks logging

Tags: .net, microsoft.extensions.logging

Great that MS standardized logging with the ILogger interface (MEL), making it easy for us to set up common logging. But a side effect of frameworks (EF, ASP.NET MVC etc.) doing proper logging and sharing the LoggerFactory in the ServiceProvider, is that Errors are logged twice. Once in the framework and second in my code handling the Exception. I find myself always disabling Logging in all other namespaces but my own to prevent this.

```
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "MyNamespace": "Warning",
    }
  }
```

How do I prevent my frameworks for logging the same ERROR as I would log in my Exception handling in my namespace? In my namespace I would have a _logger.LogError(ex, "Some Message")

**Edit**: Another unwanted side-effect when my 3rd party frameworks is logging errors, is when using retries on transient errors. It is only a error if all retries fails. How would the IT Operations deals with false errors, if I do not disable logging errors from my 3rd party frameworks?

Comment: Disabling logging in all other namespaces except your own is not a recommended practice. 
For example, you can set the logging level to Warning for the "Microsoft" and "System" categories to avoid logging duplicate errors from the framework, while setting the logging level to Information for your own namespace to log more detailed information:

"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Microsoft": "Warning",
"System": "Warning",
"MyNamespace": "Information"
}
}

This way, you can still benefit from the framework's logging while ensuring that your own logging is not duplicated.

Comment: Recommended by whom? Sounds like you're asking for opinions, which is not something Stack Overflow really does. Typically one uses a log parser (e.g., Splunk, etc.) to pull together the different logs and dedupe them.

Comment: @FaizanButt but would exactly that configuration give me two ERROR log entries if I also handle and log the error?

Comment: @HereticMonkey often I am logging to a rolling file appender

Comment: @FaizanButt added more information to the question after "Edit"

Comment: @HereticMonkey added more information to the question after "Edit"